# How do I zoom in on the crossbow?

Tags: dishonored

I purchased the upgrade for allowing Corvo to zoom in using the crossbow. I can see a small telescoping gadget on the crossbow.

However, when I press the key binding for zooming in, it doesn't happen. I tried changing the zoom button to keys such as <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or <kbd>x</kbd>, and even tried resetting all key bindings to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

On PC by default if you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> you will use your optic lens and <kbd>F</kbd> to increase your zoom level. Kind of an odd key but I am sure you can change that.

Comment: Alt doesn't work :( I don't know if this problem has to do with using windows on a mac ( boot camp )

Comment: Are you using a Mac? I don't recall there being differences in the keybindings for that but there might be. @1neFabric

Comment: Yes, I am using a mac. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Are you using windows 10? @1neFabric I have been reading problems with windows 10 and Bootcamp.

Comment: I believe I am using 8.1 pro. Thanks for your help =)

Comment: The only real help I may be able to provide (since I am a PC user not a Mac user) is providing you with help on remapping your keyboard which may be the problem. [Here is a link on how to remap your keys on bootcamp](http://www.howtogeek.com/197365/how-to-remap-windows-keyboard-shortcuts-in-boot-camp-on-a-mac/)

Comment: This is a good lead. Thank you. Once I try it I will get back with an update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49866/discussion-between-1nefabric-and-ramirez).